# How can I disable the checkbox in a Details List after certain numbers of item selection?

Tags: reactjs, office-ui-fabric, fluent-ui, fluentui-react, detailslist

I have a fluent UI details list component which contains onRenderCheckbox method. We are using this method to render a custom checkbox. Now the requirement is after 'N' number of item selection those checkbox should be disabled and if someone deselect one item (the selection is 'N-1'), then again those checkbox should be enabled.

Can anyone please help me with this? thanks in advance.